# HighCharts getJson - Unable to display

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Json Returned by my Server

```
{
    "data": [{
        "name": "name",
        "data": ["[Date.UTC(2017, 01, 25), 89]",
                 "[Date.UTC(2017, 01, 26), 99]",
                 "[Date.UTC(2017, 02, 02), 106]",
                 "[Date.UTC(2017, 02, 04), 102]",
                 "[Date.UTC(2017, 02, 07), 110]",
                 "[Date.UTC(2017, 10, 31), 155]"]
    }]
}
```

The code i'm using is from just data is generated by me (Above)
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time

My Javascript Code

```
Please Remove one T from bit ly
    $.getJSON('http://bitt.ly/2zpoZqT', function (csv) {
        console.log(csv['data']);
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Keyword Tracking'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Top 20 Keywords'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                month: '%e. %b',
                year: '%b'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Date'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Snow depth (m)'
            },
            min: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} m'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },

        series: csv['data']
    });

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the good attributes `series` to your object json return in the success call `$.getJSON` as you did. But this case create a attribute `series` as the script need and `affect` the value of `data` to `series` and `delete data` are you are done.

```js
    $.getJSON('http://bitt.ly/2zpoZqT', function (csv) {
        console.log(csv['data']);
        csv.series = csv.data;//new attribute series affected to data
        delete csv.data; //delete data to have the good object
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Keyword Tracking'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Top 20 Keywords'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                month: '%e. %b',
                year: '%b'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Date'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Snow depth (m)'
            },
            min: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} m'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },

        series: csv['data']
    });

    });
```

Comment: not working , isit because i need to change  series: csv['data'] ?

Comment: yes as your example expose the good schema need to be used http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-irregular-time/ i guess is a `patch` no a good way so do it your self inside your API or tell the api server to send the good object.

Comment: i'm using laravel, php ... u mean the way i'm generating the data is wrong/bad? It's basically array and object, cant think of another way to properly do it

Comment: yes post you PHP code you need to adapt the array generate by your script. Or just change the data attribute parent to series.

Comment: i've from controller made it a string exactly highchart would accept if i paste it , but series: csv.data <<< it will just show variable , it doesnt print the result out

Comment: Just think that json is a map and is strict because behind this attributes you got some really methods as  `object.prototype.series` i guess this is a function loops of datas and if you change is name as you did `data` in your object json. the data can't be added, because there is no methods data for this job. https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/how-to-set-options

Comment: yea but it doesn't make sense to pre-load series , that thing can be dynamic too .. this is so weird , i thought AJAX should be easier to deal with HighCharts ? Now i have to render  it with View instead of using Ajax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158008/discussion-between-headmax-and-codeguru).